# Is it possible to auto adjust volume based on average and max decibel levels on a sound?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

The objective is make all items in a playlist have the same volume so that the user doesn't have to readjust to every song.

I am using  [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) 
and this is the website I came up with that could use this feature : [wavecat](http://wave.cat/)

Comment: I can't imagine it being pleasant to hear "Me and a Gun" (which is supposed to be whispered) at the same volume as "The William Tell Overature" (which is supposed to boom). This would only make sense if your playlist consisted entirely of very similar song styles.

Comment: Sure it's possible, but you'd probably want to get data about the song on the back end, and just feed that to javascript, something like {src: 'whatever.mp3, maxDB: 10, avgDB: 8}. You wouldn't want to get data like that using javascript, it'd be a performance nightmare.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want!!